# Python Docker SDK

Tags: python-2.7, docker

So my aim is from python, build a docker image and then run the image in a container. I'm able to build the image and then run the container however the container is returning the following

```
'/bin/sh -c python -c parser.py' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-python2
MAINTAINER Ryan Woods <ryan.woods@telent.com>
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -c parser.py
```

I also tried with this Dockerfile

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-python2
MAINTAINER Ryan Woods <ryan.woods@telent.com>
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ['python', '-c', 'parser.py']
```

However that returned the following:

```
Command 'None' in image '29e73dc207' returned non-zero exit status 127: /bin/sh: [python,: not found
```

My aim for this is to just create a new docker image/container programatically and then run a python script within this container/image and collect the logs.

Comment: What command are you using to build and run these Dockerfiles?

Comment: I'm building it in my Django application using the following:

`image = \
                client.images.build(path=self._base + "Script_FrontEnd/networking_scripts/Juniper/Inventory_CSV", tag=str(_uuid))[0]`       
`container = client.containers.run(image.short_id.replace("sha256:", ""))`                
`print(container.logs())`

Comment: Do you think you could start with it at the command line first and see if you can get it running there first?

Comment: `ryan@frontned:~$ sudo docker run 354c5c34f7d1
/bin/sh: [python2,: not found
ryan@frontned:~$
`

Comment: The CMD line must be `["python2", ...]` with double quotes.  Single quotes aren't valid.

Comment: And that fixed it..... Wow a simple mistake. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Dockerfile with Docker 1.18+, code in ./app folder for clarity.

```
FROM python:2-alpine
#FROM python:3-alpine

COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["parser.py"]
```